# How to prove for any point $P$ inside an equilateral triangle $ABC$, $PA+PB > PC$

Tags: geometry

Prove that, for any  point $P$ inside an equilateral triangle $ABC$ , $PA+PB \gt PC$.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck in your (attempted) proof.

Comment: Perhaps show $PA+PB$ exceeds the side length and the side length exceeds $PC$.

Comment: In fact, for any $P$ on the plane, $PA+PB\geq PC$.  The equality holds if and only if $P$ lies on the arc $AB$ not containing $C$ of the circumcircle of $ABC$.  This is due to Ptolemy's Inequality.

Answer (score 4):

As @David Mitra mentioned,

According to the Triangle Inequality,we have

$$PA+PB\ge AB$$

And as for all point $P$, there always exists a point $R$ laying on arc $AB$ centered at $C$  where $RC=AC=BC=AB\ge PC$

[image]

Therefore $$PA+PB\ge PC$$